# Is it necessary to divide a file into chunks for encryption

Tags: python, encryption, cryptography, aes, pycrypto

I was reading the code for a [ransom ware](https://github.com/z7ev3n/ransomware/blob/master/ransomcrypto.py). As per the code, the author had divided the files into 64 kb chunks to encrypt . I am unable to understand why.

Comment: Because he is probably using a **block-cipher**.

Comment: @sascha Why given that the block size is 128-bits for AES?

Comment: Possibly to limit the memory footprint vs loading the whole file into memory as would be needed in that implementation.  The top line of your linked code is a link to its origin here on stackoverflow, why not add a comment @ the author and ask for clarification.

Comment: If any of the given answers solved your problem, you may [accept](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/266187) one of them. If it didn't, then please expand on what is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the code, the encryptor reads 1024 * blocksize of bytes (actually 16 KiB) as a single chunk and uses the same cipher object to encrypt each chunk separately.

This must be done in order to be able to encrypt large files, because some files are simply too large to be read in full into the memory, then encrypted and then written back. That alone means that the free memory must be more than three times higher than the size of the file that would need to be encrypted.

Since PyCrypto doesn't have a stream-based implementation of its ciphers, this is the closest that fulfills the same task by maintaining a small memory footprint.

Generally, the encryption of each chunk would produce independent ciphertext chunks that would need to be read back in the same chunked fashion as they were written, but this is not necessary here. AES-CBC XORs the current plaintext block with the previous ciphertext block. If it's the first block, then the IV is used as the previous ciphertext block. Since the IV is never reset on the cipher object it will always hold previous ciphertext block. The result is that the produced ciphertext is actually equivalent to encryption as a single large chunk.

---

For reference, I'm talking about this:

```
def encrypt(in_file, out_file, password, key_length=32):
    bs = AES.block_size
    salt = Random.new().read(bs - len('Salted__'))
    key, iv = derive_key_and_iv(password, salt, key_length, bs)
    cipher = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CBC, iv)
    out_file.write('Salted__' + salt)
    finished = False
    while not finished:
        chunk = in_file.read(1024 * bs)
        if len(chunk) == 0 or len(chunk) % bs != 0:
            padding_length = (bs - len(chunk) % bs) or bs
            chunk += padding_length * chr(padding_length)
            finished = True
    out_file.write(cipher.encrypt(chunk))
```

Answer (score 0):

Why is unknown and was a choice by the attack code writer.

It is not necessary to limit file sizes to 64KB using current encryption methods such as AES. Most implementations handle files of any size although it is wise to limit the size to 2^68 bytes for AES.